# Timestamp older than current time if else statement

Tags: php, datetime

Im testing an online/offline function with timestamp from the database against DateTime NOW.

But I cant figure out how to set interval time on lets say 5 minutes.
If the user has not done anything in 5 minutes, appear offline.

DateTime NOW will always be bigger than Database time.
Any ideas on how to set the interval time on the statement ?

This is what i have so far,

```
// $user_info['activity'] 2013-04-27 19:27:39 //

$dateTime = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw'));
if($user_info['activity']>$dateTime){
echo 'user Online';
}else{
echo 'user inactive';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something liKe this might work

```
$now = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw'));
$last_activity = new DateTime($user_info['activity']); 
$last_activity->modify('+5 minutes');

if($now > $last_activity){
    echo 'user inactive';
}else{
    echo 'user online';
}
```

Comment: Why not using `DateTime::diff()`? it is intended for this

Comment: @john Conde, it almost work like a charm, but I don't know if the minutes is working after minutes. 
if i have the +5 users that been inactive for more than hours still appears online.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to change your database timestamp to be a DateTime object as well and then use the [DateTime::diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method for comparison.

```
$dateTime1 = new DateTime(strtotime($user_info['activity']), new DateTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw'));
$dateTime2 = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw'));

$interval = $dateTime1->diff($dateTime2);
```

This will allow you to determine the interval and do a comparison using it.

Comment: The problem is that dateTime does not support On Update current
But if i solve the problem with the update this looks like a perfect solution

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DateTime::diff()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) for this:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$activity = $user_info['activity'];
// get difference between the two dates   
$difference = $now->diff($activity);

// ->i contains the minutes
if($difference->i >= 5) {
    echo "logged out";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this recently, like this:

```
$time = time();
$last_activity = //time from db
$time_since = $time - $last_activity
```

Then clean up `$time_since` if necessary for your application.